# Show zero values for a column after performing conditional groupby count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've a dataframe as mentioned below:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDMa5.png]

I'm using the following code to get the count of `resolved` for all the items in column `A`:

`resolved = df[df['B']== 'resolved'].groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].size()`

and similarly for `unresolved`:

`unresolved = df[df['B']== 'unresolved'].groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].size()`

For `unresolved`, `SRVCAM-AM BI-Data` doesn't have `unresolved` value in column `B`. So, the resulting dataframe will not have it

The result obtained for `unresolved`is as below:

`work_queue                            count
SRVCAM-AM BI-Reports Admin              1`

but I want the result as follows:

`work_queue                            count
SRVCAM-AM BI-Reports Admin              1
SRVCAM-AM BI-Data                       0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare column `B` and aggregate `sum` - `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
resolved = (df['B'] == 'resolved').groupby(df['A'], as_index=False).sum().astype(int)
```

If want all columns by `B` use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
resolved = pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used the first solution and I got the right answer.